# Need 404 behaviour for blank parent page

Tags: pages, 404-error

My pages look like this

- Home (Has content)
- Products (No content)

  - Product 1 (Has content)
  - Product 2 (Has content)
  - Product 3 (Has content)
- Contact (Has content)

I only created the "Products" page so the navigation makes sense in the Pages structure, however it has no content so I need it to show the 404.php when you try to access it via the direct URL:

```
http://example.com/products/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In functions.php

```
function productsPageRedirect_404() {
    global $post;
    if( is_page('products') ) {
       global $wp_query;
       $wp_query->set_404();
       status_header(404);
    }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'productsPageRedirect_404' );
```